# NivoSlider not working in Bootstrap site

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nivo-slider

For some reason the NivoSlider is not working on this page, I have tried finding a fix but I cant seem to figure out why its not working.. Please see link: http://wsieworksstaging.com/kww/about-us.html

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Comment: Please describe carefully to avoid down votes. Do paste the problem code for future questions. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got this code at the top of your page:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        startSlide:0, //Set starting Slide (0 index)
        slideshowEnd: function(){$('#slider').data('nivo:vars').stop = true;} 
    });
});
```

The problem is that you aren't loading the jQuery library or the NivoSlider library until near the end of your page. Because of this, the Javascript engine in your browser doesn't know what a `$` means or what `nivoSlider` means. You need to move this code thats at the top of your page to somewhere below where you are loading jQuery and Nivo.

**EDIT**

I think you are having a jQuery conflict man. Try this code instead:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(window).load(function() {
    j('#slider').nivoSlider({
        startSlide:0, //Set starting Slide (0 index)
        slideshowEnd: function(){$('#slider').data('nivo:vars').stop = true;} 
    });
});
```

Comment: @SixFootUnda -- That fixed one of your issues. The reason its still not working is because I think NivoSlider requires jQuery 1.9 or higher. You are using version 1.7. Try referencing 1.9 instead.

Comment: I dont have a copy of 1.9 but I used the code to access the latest version and put that in, doesnt seem to fix the main issue I have..